# App installer id not set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, google-analytics

In google analytics page I saw App Installer ID below Acquisition/ App Market Place with 4 categories:1, com.android.vending, 2, com.google.android.feedback 3, com.airnauts.vietapps and 4, Not set.  now how can I set app installer id for 4.
I want to give a name "Sideload". please help me

Answer (score 1):

Check package name in your project's AndroidManifest.xml file for particular Sideload module and check applicationID in build.gradle file

Comment: Sorry I did not understand , please inform me how can i set app installer id for sideloads.

Comment: In your project navigate through above files and check the package name exists or not...

Comment: In both file package name existing.

Comment: What is the package name for it ?

Comment: com.myproject.myanalytics

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/iGflHFE3qho
Checked this as per defined package name it will show categories ..

Comment: The link you have provided is for iPhone . My problem is for android.